# due date by priority

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to plug in a formula into SharePoint Designer to auto calculate the due date by priority. We have a [Priority Level] field of Critical, High, Med and Low. The TAT Guidelines are as follows:

- Critical = 24 hour
- High = 5 days
- Med = 10 days
- Low = 15 days

What formula do I need to add to calculate the date to automatically enter into our [Due Date] field?

Comment: Hi 
Are you okay with the answer provided ?

Answer (score 1):

You create a 2013 workflow for this calculation and update the value in Due date field to display in the view rather than doing it in SharePoint designer

1. Create a List workflow using SharePoint 2013 designer( Select 2013 workflow in drop down)
2. it open workflow editor look like below image.
3. Keep the If condition in that if condition

   - add time to date and Update list item actions as shown in below picture

     [image]
     [image]
4. After that you can add multiple else if condition in the workflow editor it looks like the complete all 4 conditions

[image]
 5. Select the Start workflow automatically when item created and updates as shown in below picture

[image]

6. Finally save and publish the workflow and it will work as you expected. now add the task in task list and check the due date on your page.